# Google Compute Engine GPU

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Google recently added support for GPUs in their cloud service.

I'm trying to follow the instructions found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus) to start a machine with a GPU. Running this script on Windows:

```
gcloud beta compute instances create gpu-instance-1^
 --machine-type n1-standard-2^
 --zone us-east1-d^
 --accelerator type=nvidia-tesla-k80,count=1^
 --image-family ubuntu-1604-lts^
 --image-project ubuntu-os-cloud^
 --maintenance-policy TERMINATE^
 --restart-on-failure^
```

with gcloud command line tool version `146.0.0` fails, saying:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.instances.create) unknown collection [compute.acceleratorTypes]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have quota for GPUs? Trials do not support GPUs at this time. Also, can you create an instance from the web UI?

Comment: Yes, we have a quota for 4 GPU dies in `us-east`, and we're paying (i.e. not doing a trial). I looked for quite a while for an option to do it in the web UI but couldn't find anything. I was trying just a couple hours after the quota had been approved, so maybe if I try again on Monday it'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was never able to get the `gcloud` utility working. Using the API did work. Of note, when posting the API request (instructions on the same page as the `gcloud` instructions, [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus)) the key that creates an instance with a GPU is `guestAccelerators`. This key does not have an analogous option in `gcloud`.

Copying the API request as it appears on the instructions page linked above.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/zones/[ZONE]/instances?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
{
  "machineType": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/zones/[ZONE]/machineTypes/n1-highmem-2",
  "disks":
  [
    {
      "type": "PERSISTENT",
      "initializeParams":
      {
        "diskSizeGb": "[DISK_SIZE]",
        "sourceImage": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/[IMAGE_PROJECT]/global/images/family/[IMAGE_FAMILY]"
      },
      "boot": true
    }
  ],
  "name": "[INSTANCE_NAME]",
  "networkInterfaces":
  [
    {
      "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/global/networks/[NETWORK]"
    }
  ],
  "guestAccelerators":
  [
    {
      "acceleratorCount": [ACCELERATOR_COUNT],
      "acceleratorType": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/zones/[ZONE]/acceleratorTypes/[ACCELERATOR_TYPE]"
    }
  ],
  "scheduling":
  {
    "onHostMaintenance": "terminate",
    "automaticRestart": true
  },
  "metadata":
  {
    "items":
    [
      {
        "key": "startup-script",
        "value": "[STARTUP_SCRIPT]"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to ensure you have the latest version of the gcloud utility installed in order to use certain GCP features.

Try running this command or read the below docs on how to update your gcloud utility:

```
gcloud components update
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update